# XMPPError connecting to chat.facebook.com (Permission denied) logging in to facebook chat with asmack

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, chat, smack

As you may know, there's not a single organized documentation on how to properly login to Facebook using the asmack library. I've somehow managed to find some codes in the net to at least allow me to login to my account but why do I keep getting the following exception:

> XMPPError connecting to chat.facebook.com:5222.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to chat.facebook.com:5222. -- caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

Here's the code:

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn)).setOnClickListener(
      new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            ConnectionConfiguration config =
                  new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222,
                  "chat.facebook.com");
            config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);

            Connection conn = new XMPPConnection(config);
            try {
               conn.connect();
               SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);

               ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(instance,
                     "", "Loading...");
               conn.login(login_field.getText().toString(),
                     pwd_field.getText().toString(),
                     login_field.getText().toString() + "/fbchat");
               loading.hide();

               new AlertDialog.Builder(instance).setMessage(conn.getUser())
                  .create().show();
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
               new AlertDialog.Builder(instance).setMessage(e.toString())
               .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     dialog.cancel();
                  }
               })
               .create().show();
            }
         }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obvious potential explanation - do you have the [`INTERNET`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission in your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Without this, you will be unable to access network resources.

---

EDIT:

Where in the manifest are you requesting the INTERNET permission? It's location can make a difference, and it will fail silently. It needs to be at the top-level (under the `<manifest>` tag, not attached to an activity, for example). Of course, if you added it via Eclipse, it's probably in the correct place already:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.samplesync"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <activity>
        ...
    </activity>
</manifest>
```

Alternatively, how are you connecting to the internet? This may also indicate that the required ports are being blocked by a firewall (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293109/permission-denied-while-connecting-to-a-page-even-with-internet-permission))

Comment: looks like your edit worked! cuz im getting a bunch of new errors now, like server timeout or something. my uses-permission was initially located under the </activity> tag. cant believe that got me stuck for 6 hours

Comment: It'd be great if the Android tools flagged it as an error since there's clearly only one place it can be of use, but I guess it's valid XML so it gets through.